# Is there a way to make sure a highlited parent widget remains highlighted when selecting a child widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, highlight

I have a radiobutton that highlights the corresponding LabelFrame.

Each LabelFrame has an Entry widget as a child.
When the Entry widget is selected to type in some input, the parent LabelFrame loses the given highlightbackground color (from cyan to gray) but keeps the same highlightthickness.

Is there a way to keep the given highlightbackground color?

(windows 7 64, pycharm 2019.2)

Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


class doSomeStuff(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.radioBtnVar = StringVar()  # radiobutton variable

        # main canvas

        pwdCanvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        pwdCanvas.pack()

        # choiceLabelFrame
        choiceLabelFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(pwdCanvas, text='Choice LabelFrame (ttk)')
        choiceLabelFrame.grid(column=0, row=11, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')

        # radio button 1
        rbtn1 = ttk.Radiobutton(choiceLabelFrame, text='A', variable=self.radioBtnVar, value='PCG', command=self.colorLabels)
        rbtn1.pack(side='left')

        # radio button 2
        rbtn2 = ttk.Radiobutton(choiceLabelFrame, text='B', variable=self.radioBtnVar, value='UG', command=self.colorLabels)
        rbtn2.pack(side='right')

        # LabelFrame1, left side
        self.LabelFrame1 = tk.LabelFrame(pwdCanvas, text="LabelFrame 1 (tk)", bd=0)  # I use tk to have access to the 'highlightbackground' option
        self.LabelFrame1.grid(column=0, row=12, sticky='nsew', padx=3, pady=3)

        entry1Label = ttk.Label(self.LabelFrame1, text='Entry 1')
        entry1Label.grid(column=0, row=11, sticky='w')

        self.labelEntry1 = ttk.Entry(self.LabelFrame1, state='disabled')
        self.labelEntry1.grid(column=1, row=11, sticky='w')

        # LabelFrame2, right side
        self.LabelFrame2 = tk.LabelFrame(pwdCanvas, text="LabelFrame 2 (tk)", bd=0)
        self.LabelFrame2.grid(column=1, row=12, sticky='nw', padx=3, pady=3)

        entry2Label = ttk.Label(self.LabelFrame2, text='Entry 2')
        entry2Label.grid(column=0, row=0)

        labelEntry2 = ttk.Entry(self.LabelFrame2, state='disabled')
        labelEntry2.grid(column=1, row=0)

    def colorLabels(self):  # activates and highlights the chosen option
        if self.radioBtnVar.get() == 'PCG':
            for child in self.LabelFrame1.winfo_children():
                child.config(state='enabled')
            self.LabelFrame1.config(highlightbackground='cyan', highlightthickness=2)

            for child in self.LabelFrame2.winfo_children():
                child.config(state='disabled')
            self.LabelFrame2.config(highlightthickness=0)

        elif self.radioBtnVar.get() == 'UG':
            for child in self.LabelFrame2.winfo_children():
                child.config(state='enabled')
            self.LabelFrame2.config(highlightbackground='cyan', highlightthickness=2)

            for child in self.LabelFrame1.winfo_children():
                child.config(state='disabled')
            self.LabelFrame1.config(highlightthickness=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = doSomeStuff()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to get what I want.

```
    def colorLabels(self):
        if self.radioBtnVar.get() == 'PCG':
            for child in self.LabelFrame1.winfo_children():
                child.config(state='enabled')
            self.LabelFrame1.config(highlightbackground='cyan', highlightcolor='cyan', highlightthickness=2)

            for child in self.LabelFrame2.winfo_children():
                child.config(state='disabled')
            self.LabelFrame2.config(highlightthickness=0)

        elif self.radioBtnVar.get() == 'UG':
            for child in self.LabelFrame2.winfo_children():
                child.config(state='enabled')
            self.LabelFrame2.config(highlightbackground='cyan', highlightcolor='cyan', highlightthickness=2)

            for child in self.LabelFrame1.winfo_children():
                child.config(state='disabled')
            self.LabelFrame1.config(highlightthickness=0)
```

I simply added 'highlightcolor='cyan''.
As explained here [effbot.org](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) :

- 'highlightbackground' is used when the widget doesn’t have focus.
- 'highlightcolor'  is used when the widget has focus.

That way my widget keeps its highlighted contour even if it's not in focus.

Comment: You should accept your own answer (click on the tick below the answer score) so that people see that your problem is solved.

Comment: @  j_4321: I've got a msg saying "you can accept your own answer tomorrow". I guess I'll have to wait.

Comment: Ok, no problem I had forgotten this rule.

Answer (score 0):

The `highlightthickness` attribute is specifically for highlighting which widget has the keyboard focus. It serves as a clue for the user when traversing the UI with the keyboard.

Because it is tied directly to which widget has focus, and because you can only have focus in one widget at a time, it's not possible to use that feature to highlight more than one thing at a time.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting. Is there any other way to get the same result?

Comment: @FelixTheCat: sure, one simple solution is to use another frame or canvas around the widget, and change the color of the surrounding frame.

Comment: @ Bryan Oakley: thanks for putting me on the right track.